# Problem with Cufon. Need Help?

Tags: javascript, css, web, fonts, cufon

I'm working on a simple site but i have problem showing the cufon font, this is my first time using this feature. I'm using firefox 3.6.18

```
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/cufon-yui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="javascript/corbel-bold_700.font.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        Cufon.replace('h1'); 
        Cufon.replace('selector'); 
        Cufon.replace('#sub1');
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="header">
<div id="logo" onclick="window.document.location.href='http://localhost/site/'"></div>
<div id="navigation">
    <div class="menu">

  <h1>ABOUT</h1>
  <h1>GALLERY</h1>
  <h1>CONTACT</h1>

</div> 
</div>
</div>

        <script type="text/javascript"> Cufon.now(); </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The H1 is showing but not in its cufon text. Help! Thanks in Advance!!

Comment: Are you getting any javascript errors?

Comment: nope, nothing. that's another thing, no error warnings are showing up.

Comment: The code you've posted works fine for me. Could you post an example of it not working on jsfiddle.net?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t9gny/

There you go, I'm really new at this so if i did something wrong, pardon me. And thanks a lot.

Comment: Excellent, thanks. Could you now post an example that doesn't throw a load of javascript errors? I think you might need to inline the Cufon stuff in the HTML before you perform your calls to it.

Comment: Oh, which do you mean? or what do you mean? The one i pasted on the javascript side?

Comment: Yeah, I think if you include the contents of the cufon file and the font file in a script block before you call cufon then that should do the trick.

Comment: Sorry, but i'm not familiar with this. I added <script language="javascript"></script> before the <script src="cufon-yui> etc. lines. Do you mean that?

Comment: Yes, if you paste the contents of both javascript files into that script element then that should do what's needed. After that you need to hit "Update" at the top and post the updated URL.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/t9gny/5/

I included the contents of cufon_yui.js and font.js files in the javascript window. Thanks again.

Comment: Are you really sure that you're not getting any javascript errors? I get "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ." from the font definition JS you posted on jsfiddle.net. These went away when I replaced it with a freshly downloaded font definition JS file.

Comment: It seems the problem really is in the js file. I downloaded a set of js files from cufon's github and it worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: That's OK. Could you accept my answer so that people can see quickly that this question's been answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm getting a javascript error from the font file that you posted. Try with a different font and see if it works. If it does then give it another go with your file.

If your font still doesn't work then it sounds like a problem with Cufon's JS generation.